# HttpResponseException not accepting HttpStatusCode

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpresponse, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to raise a `HttpResponseException` as described in this screencast (about 1 minute in)

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

But the app won't compile as it throws the following error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException.HttpResponseException(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage)' has some invalid arguments
```

The documentation on msdn says it has a constructor that accepts the `HttpResponseMessage` enum. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh835324%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Could you also post your actual code?

Comment: When you create the HttpResponseException and hit the right paren, do you see two constructors as the docs show or just one?  If just one, then you are limited to an HttpResponseMessage....OR....you are using a version of the framework that is different than the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using the RC, this has changed. Try:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
```

Comment: And if I need to send some message to client?

Comment: @Zote - Create a HttpResponseMessage variable, set the Content property, then pass into the HttpResponseException. Or if you want to get really fancy, I've written a post on [returning a custom error type](http://smlync.tumblr.com/post/23104849655/returning-custom-error-data-type-in-asp-net-web-api).

Comment: what do you mean by the RC? And how do I know if I'm using the RC?

Comment: At the time of the post, the Web API Release Candidate had just come out, which had changed a few things from the Beta when the screencast mentioned in the original post had been made. If you've downloaded the Web API since the beginning of June or are using it as part of the recent VS 2012 RTM, the format mentioned in my answer applies.

Answer (score 6):

Having just run into this problem myself, I am glad to see the answer provided by smlync, though, its disappointing to see the API in this case has turned to greater verbosity! IMHO, the following leans towards the description 'monstrous', particularly when this exception (above all) fills every controller many times over:

```
    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
```

I may be using this instead, perhaps some of you would find it useful as well:

```
    throw new Http404NotFoundException();
```

With the following placed whereever you would like:

```
public class Http404NotFoundException : HttpResponseException
{
    public Http404NotFoundException()
        : base(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)) { }
}
```

Wouldn't this be cleaner, beloved ASP.NET WebApi team? If only for this status code, though maybe throw in a couple other of the very common status code equivalents.